# C# Entity Framework join tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to get the same results as with a SQL query using Entity Framework method syntax.

[image]

SQL query :

```
select 
    mr.*, mrf.userId as RequesterUserId, mrt.UserId as ReceiverUserId 
from 
    MoneyRequests mr
inner join  
    MoneyReqFrom mrf on mr.MoneyRequestId = mrf.MoneyRequestId
inner join  
    MoneyReqTo mrt on mr.MoneyRequestId = mrt.MoneyRequestId
where 
    mr.MoneyRequestId = 'acfc8008-4cf7-47ec-a3fe-0fe245af77cc'
```

EF Linq method syntax :

```
var moneyreqResponse = context.MoneyRequests
                              .Join(context.MoneyReqFroms, 
                                      mr => mr.MoneyRequestId, 
                                      mrf => mrf.MoneyRequestId, 
                                      (mr, mrf) => new 
                                                   { 
                                                       MoneyRequestId = mr.MoneyRequestId,
                                                       Amount = mr.Amount,
                                                       RequestType = mr.RequestType,
                                                       CreationDate = mr.CreationDate,
                                                       RequesterUserId = mrf.UserId 
                                                    }) 
                              .Join(context.MoneyReqTos, 
                                       mr => mr.MoneyRequestId, 
                                       mrt => mrt.MoneyRequestId,
                                       (mr, mrt) => new 
                                                    { 
                                                        MoneyRequestId = mr.MoneyRequestId,
                                                        Amount = mr.Amount, 
                                                        RequestType = mr.RequestType,
                                                        CreationDate = mr.CreationDate,
                                                        ReceiverUserId = mrt.UserId, 
                                                        Email = mrt.Email 
                                                    }) 
                              .Where(fullEntry => fullEntry.MoneyRequestId == "acfc8008-4cf7-47ec-a3fe-0fe245af77cc") 
                              .ToList();
```

I retrieve the data from the database except the column `RequesterUserId`.

Do you know why?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you retrieve the data *except* that column? Is it ˙null˙? Or not included in the object?

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns a `MoneyRequests` type, which I belive does not contain `RequesterUserId`.

You should define a new type with all the properties you need (those returned by the join)  and add it to your DbContext.

Also probably you want to mark your new type as [keyless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations)